# Python and R path

Tags: python, r, path

I have added python and R path to the system path throughout the following python code.

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys
program_path = r"C:\Users\asahmed\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library"
subprocess.Popen(f'setx path "%path%;{program_path}"')
```

and this code successfully runs for R path and python path,
and I ensured that they added to the system variable path.

But when try to run R or Python from CMD it doesn't run.

Comment: Did you try to change CMD path?. ie. echo %PATH%

Answer (score 0):

When writing in Python, backslashes are considered escape characters.  Either use forward-slashes or escape your backslashes with another backslash.

your path should look like this:

```
program_path = "C:\\Users\\asahmed\\OneDrive\\Documents\\R\\win-library"
```

or

```
program_path = "C:/Users/asahmed/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,